# I want to hide ckeditor toolbar without removing it

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

I want to hide ckeditor toolbar without removing it, so that I can keep using the plugins (math).
Something like set visible false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I did id check the generated code add make css hide the class for the header

```
.cke_top{display:none;}
```

Or

```
.cke_top{Visibility:hidden;}
```